# RCP the default perspective bar only contains one perspective shortcut?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, perspective

When you have two perspectives, the perspective bar contains only one perspective shortcut, if you want to tab into the other one, you must click the menu to pick it. So, how can I put the perspectives' shortcuts both into the perspective bar just like in Eclipse itself?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to do it like this: In your class, which extends `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` override `preWindowOpen` method and add following code:

```
@Override
public void preWindowOpen() {
    IPersistentPreferenceStore prefStore = (IPersistentPreferenceStore) PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore();
    prefStore.setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS, "your_perspective_id_2, your_perspective_id_2, ... your_perspective_id_n");
    try {
        prefStore.save();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perspective bar (toolbar with buttons) only shows the perspectives that are currently open. Alexander Gavrilov's solution let's you place the shortcuts to the drop-down menu of "Open Perspective" item, but this doesn't work on e4 ([bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423136)).